# Service registry with Eureka and springboot

Tags: spring-cloud

I have a micro-service written in spring boot and registered with Eureka. All I need to do is test the circuit breaker using Hystrix i.e I have an endpoint which will fetch me some data from the db and in case if anything goes wrong i have a fallback method to execute which gives me a mocked response. Everything works fine with the code I have written.

Thee problem I face is that during start of my application it successfully registers with eureka with status UP. The moment I shutdown my database to test the circuit breaker Eureka marks the service as down but still the service works fine.

I really could not understand the reason why Eureka says the service as DOWN.

Comment: Do you have `eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true`?

Comment: Yes. I have set it to true. After some time spent on digging I found that /health endpoint of my service threw database exception and its because of that reason Eureka was marking my service as down.

Comment: you should custom your own database exception so that you can test  your circuit breaker.

Comment: I am sorry Demon Coldmist. What do you mean by custom your own database exception? But still making API level changes makes no difference to spring boot actuators /health endpoint because it picks db config from properties.